Find generating function for the number of partitions which are not divisible by $3$.
I'm trying to find the generating function for the number of partitions into parts, which are not divisible by $3,$ weighted by the sum of the parts. My idea is that we get the following generating function:
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^4}\frac{1}{1-x^5}\ldots = \prod_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{(1-x^{3k-1})(1-x^{3k-2})}.
$$
However, I cant seem to show that this is equivalent to:
$$
\prod_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{(1-x^n)}\prod_{k\geq 1} (1-x^{3k}).
$$
Since I know this should be the the generating function.
So either my original idea is wrong or my manipulation technique needs some freshing up.
Any help is much appreciated.

$\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_4a_5a_7a_8\cdots}=\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7a_8\cdots}\cdot (a_3a_6\cdots)$

@MichalAdamaszek Thank you for this clear hint, now I see it.
